# Mock/Patch specific object method inside a class method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I know the title is quite confusing, but for the sake of clarity, I created a sample of what I have to transpose:

Let's say I have this code in `class_file.py`

```py
class CarDealership:
    def allow_car_out_of_the_dealership(self, car):
        logger.info(f"Driving out of the dealership")
        
        drivers_license = car.driver.wallet.get_drivers_license()

        if drivers_license:
            try:
                allow_car_removal(car, drivers_license)
            except:
                deny_car_removal(car, drivers_license)
```

I'm trying to test a situation where the method `deny_car_removal` is called. `get_valid_license()` is a method specific to `driver.wallet` and is not otherwise imported or referenced in `class_file.py` in any way, shape or form.

The problem is that the code goes a completely different way if `get_valid_license` does not return anything valid in the real situation. I'm trying to patch the `drivers_license` so I can eventually bring it to the point I need.

I'm guessing `test_class_file.py` should look something like this:

```py
class CarDealershipTests(BaseTestCase):
    @patch('class_file.CarDealership.deny_car_removal')
    def test_deny_car_removal(self):
        # something here
        self.assertTrue(mock_deny_car_removal.called)
```

A few things I have tried from looking at other StackOverflow answers but didn't work:

- In the test setup, mock a full `driver` instance inside the mocked `car`, like so:

```py
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self._create_car
    
    def _create_car(self):
        car = Car()
        car.driver = MagicMock()
```

- Tried using `@patch.object(class_file.CarDealership.allow_car_out_of_the_dealership, "car.driver.wallet.get_valid_license")`
- Tried using `@patch.object(class_file.CarDealership.allow_car_out_of_the_dealership, "drivers_license")`
- Tried using `@patch("class_file.CarDealership.allow_car_out_of_the_dealership.car.driver.wallet.get_valid_license")`
- Tried using `@patch("class_file.CarDealership.allow_car_out_of_the_dealership.drivers_license")`

Comment: this appears to be using the standard Python unit test framework, also with regards to your actual logic, you should be _explicit_ with respect to the exceptions that you are catching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a file with the following contents as you have shown:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CarRemovalFailure(BaseException):
    pass


class CarDealership:
    def allow_car_out_of_the_dealership(self, car):
        logger.info("Driving out of the dealership")
        
        drivers_license = car.driver.wallet.get_drivers_license()

        if drivers_license:
            try:
                allow_car_removal(car, drivers_license)
            except CarRemovalFailure:
                deny_car_removal(car, drivers_license)
```

In order to have `deny_car_removal` be called, we will need `allow_car_removal` to throw an `Exception`. This is easily done by using the [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) attribute of the `Mock` object.

I didn't incorporate any setup/tear-down up in this test but instead am illustrating how `side_effect` works and how it ends up having `deny_car_removal` be called.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from class_file import CarDealership, CarRemovalFailure


@patch("class_file.allow_car_removal")
@patch("class_file.deny_car_removal")
def test_deny_car(mock_deny, mock_allow):
    mock_allow.side_effect = CarRemovalFailure("Failed!")
    car = MagicMock()
    cd = CarDealership()

    cd.allow_car_out_of_the_dealership(car)

    car.driver.wallet.get_drivers_license.assert_called_once()
    mock_deny.assert_called_once()
```

When run it outputs the following:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ****
collected 1 item                                                               

tests/test_car.py .                                                      [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.05s ===============================
```

In your example you might not want to patch `deny_car_removal` as you are trying to test the logic, but since I don't know what that might be I patched it on my end. The point of that was to illustrate that in fact the function does get called.

Comment: Hi, Gold. Thanks for the very thorough response, but my main doubt here is how to mock ```drivers_license```. My tests are being interrupted once that function is unable to get a valid one because, well, it's a mock.

Comment: since you're passing in `car` to the function you can just create an object like I did, `car = MagickMock()`. then you just have to configure it, basically it would be `car.driver.wallet.get_drivers_license.return_value = {"fizz": "buzz"}`. then when that object is called it would return `{"fizz": "buzz"}`. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, I get it! Thanks a lot!